Unable to establish a connection using pyodbc in Python
I am trying to connect to an on premise SQL Server database using pyodbc in Python working in VS Code. I am able to connect to the server using the SQL Server extension. I believe this verifies that the driver name, server name, and database name are correct. I am running this on a Windows machine.  When I run the notebook
Any ideas on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Here's the code snippet:
conn_str = (
    f'DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};'
    f'SERVER={SERVER_NAME};'
    f'DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};'
    f'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    f'Connection Timeout=0;'
)

try:
    # Attempt to establish a connection
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    print('Connected to SQL Server')

    # Test a query
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print("Test Query Result:", row[0])

    # Close the connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    # Print detailed error information
    print("Error:", e)
    print("Connection String:", conn_str)

When I run this code, it prints out the list of drivers correctly, but I am unable to establish a connection to the database. I am getting a "no connection" error.

Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
Connection String: DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=;DATABASE=;Trusted_Connection=yes;Connection Timeout=0;Encrypt=yes;


it looks like the credentials are invalid or you dont have access. Either way, it is not making the connection.

Does your SERVER_NAME variable include an instance name, e.g., myserver\myinstance ?

Try removing the "Connection Timeout=0" portion of your conn_str variable.

A reasonable suggestion, but not the answer in this case. Once you've gained a bit more reputation you will be able to leave comments with suggestions like this.
